# Pandas groupby to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns `code` and `images`.

Column `images` is a string of `urls` joined by a comma: `<URL>,<URL2>,...`

Column `code` is NOT unique and I need to make it unique but store all images (from all variants) in a new column `images_all`.

For example:

```
code something images
1    x         url1,url2,url3
1    x         url1,url4
```

Result is:
code something images_all
1    x         url1,url2,url3,url4

I did

```
grouped = csv.groupby('code')
csv = csv.drop_duplicates(subset=['code'], keep='last')
csv['images_all'] = csv.apply(lambda r:  list(set(
    [image for image in grouped.get_group(r['code'])['images']]
)))
```

which raises:

```
KeyError: 'code'
```

But even if it didn't raise this, the problem is that images wouldn't be `[url1,url2,url3,url4]` . Instead, it would be `["url1,url2,url3","url1,url4"]`.

Do you know how to fix it?

**EDIT**

*I also want to keep other columns (they are the same for all rows with the same code, that's why I then just drop_duplicates and keep the last row)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with custom function for flatten splitted values, then converted to sets and last `join` unique values:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(set([z for y in x for z in y.split(',')]))
df['images_all'] = df.groupby('code')['images'].transform(f)
print (df)
   code something          images           images_all
0     1         x  url1,url2,url3  url1,url3,url2,url4
1     1         x       url1,url4  url1,url3,url2,url4
```